# Merging doc_count result from keyed buckets

Tags: php, elasticsearch, nosql, elasticsearch-5

I have a query like

```
'aggs' => [
                'deadline' => [
                    'date_histogram' => [
                        'field' => 'deadline',
                        'interval' => 'month',
                        'keyed' => true,
                        'format' => 'MMM'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
```

the result I am getting are buckets with keys as month names.

The problem I am facing is the buckets with the month names as keys for a previous year are over written by another month of the next year (because obviously the key is same).

I want results where doc-count of buckets of previous which are over written merge with the doc_count of the next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either add a separate  month field during indexing and perform aggregation on it or use below script

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "deadline": {
      "histogram": {
         "script":  { "inline" : "return doc['deadline'].value.getMonthOfYear()" },
        "interval": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Creating a separate month field will have better performance

Answer (score 0):

Replace the format from `MMM` to `YYYY-MMM` as below:

```
'aggs' => [
                'deadline' => [
                    'date_histogram' => [
                        'field' => 'deadline',
                        'interval' => 'month',
                        'keyed' => true,
                        'format' => 'YYYY-MMM'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
```

After this you can handle the merging process at your application level

Comment: that would fail my purpose of using keyed buckets